# How do I get my CMS website to show the newest record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I am making a content managed website in Codeigniter, but when i read out my array with a foreach it shows the oldest record at the top.

How can I make it so that the newest record  is always on top.

This is one of the functions in my controller.

```
function comments($page){
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $this->load->model("model_get");

    $config['base_url'] = base_url('main/comments/'.$this->uri->segment(3).'/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->model_get->getCommentcount();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getComments($config['per_page'], $page);
    $this->load->view('content_comment', $data);
}
```

This is my model to fetch the data.

```
function getComments($limit, $start){
        $this->db->from('comments');
        $this->db->where('blog_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->db->limit($limit, $this->uri->segment(4));
        $results = $this->db->get();

        if ($results) 
        {
            return $results->result();
        }else{

        return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

And this is my foreach to display the results.

```
<?php
    foreach($results as $row){
        $text = $row->text;
        echo "<h3>". $text ."</h3>";
        $author = $row->author;
        echo "<p>". $author ."</p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your model function after "limit" line:

```
$this->db->order_by("blog_id", "desc");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How could I not see that. ;)